# cgo result has go pointer

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am writing some go code that exports a function like that:

```
package main
import "C"

//export returnString
func returnString() string {
    //
    gostring := "hello world"
    return gostring
}
func main() {}
```

I build the `.so` and the header file by using go build `-buildmode=c-shared`, but when I call `returnString()` in my C code, I get `panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer`

Is there a way to to this in go 1.9?

Comment: Why are you returning a Go string to C code? The return value here should be allocated in C.

Comment: Do you mean I should return a CString from my go code?

Comment: Well, those are two different structures. What does the calling code need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert your go string to `*C.char`. `C.Cstring` is utility function for that.

```
package main

import "C"

//export returnString
func returnString() *C.char {
    gostring := "hello world"
    return C.CString(gostring)
}

func main() {}
```

Comment: Be careful with **CString**. You should deallocate the memory.

Comment: How do you deallocate the memory?

Comment: @HeathMitchell `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstring))` should do the trick.

Comment: @Nebril How would i call `C.free` on a value which is being returned by the function like in the above code?

Comment: You should provide another exported function says FreeString that accept pointer and call C.free. Then from main code in C you should call first returnString() then copy string data to your C string and then call FreeString.

Comment: not exact. see https://gist.github.com/helinwang/2c7bd2867ea5110f70e6431a7c80cd9b