# JNA to Go DLL - How do I get String returned from Go Func?

Tags: jna, cgo

I have a Java program that is using JNA to call a Go Func.  Here's the Interface to the Go func in Java:

```
public interface GPG extends Library {
    // GoString class maps to: C type struct { const char *p; GoInt n; }
    public class GoString extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends GoString implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public String p;
        public long n;
        protected List getFieldOrder(){
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"p","n"});
        }
    }
    // Foreign functions
    public GoString.ByValue decrypt(GoString.ByValue encString, GoString.ByValue secretKeyring, GoString.ByValue passphrase);
}
```

The func signature in Go is:

```
func decrypt(encString string, secretKeyring string, passphrase string) string
```

The Go generated C header has:

```
/* Created by "go tool cgo" - DO NOT EDIT. */

/* package command-line-arguments */


#line 1 "cgo-builtin-prolog"

#include <stddef.h> /* for ptrdiff_t below */

#ifndef GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H

typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;

#endif

/* Start of preamble from import "C" comments.  */




/* End of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


/* Start of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */
#line 1 "cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog"

#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;

/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

typedef _GoString_ GoString;
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


extern GoString decrypt(GoString p0, GoString p1, GoString p2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I call the Go Func from Java using this code:

```
                GPG gpg = (GPG) Native.loadLibrary("C:/lib/gpg.dll", GPG.class);
                GPG.GoString.ByValue encString = new GPG.GoString.ByValue();
                encString.p = value;
                encString.n = encString.p.length();
                GPG.GoString.ByValue secretKeyring = new GPG.GoString.ByValue();
                secretKeyring.p = "c:/gnupg/secring.gpg";
                secretKeyring.n = secretKeyring.p.length();
                GPG.GoString.ByValue passphrase = new GPG.GoString.ByValue();
                passphrase.p = "SecretPassPhrase";
                passphrase.n = passphrase.p.length();
                GPG.GoString.ByValue decValue = gpg.decrypt(encString, secretKeyring, passphrase);
```

Clearly the func is being called and processes up to the return of the result string.  But it then produces: "panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer"
How do I get a String result back from Go?
Using go version go1.10 windows/amd64, JNA 4.5.1, Java 1.8.0_152

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cgo result has go pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686763/cgo-result-has-go-pointer)

Comment: C.CString does not map to GoString.ByValue.  And it turns out that Go 1.10 has improved restrictions on passing Go pointers to C.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You'll need to change the Go function or add a wrapping function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GO function should looks like this:

```
//export decrypt
func decrypt(encString string, secretKeyring string, passphrase string) *C.char {
    //... your code here
    var str string = "returning string"
    return C.CString(str)
}
```

Java Interface:

```
public String decrypt(GoString.ByValue encString, GoString.ByValue secretKeyring, GoString.ByValue passphrase);
```

Comment: Also you should deallocate memory allocated by C.CString(). Safest way to do so is provide another exported function in go that would call C.free on received pointer. Then in main program after calling decrypt you should call this function. To do so better declare java returning type as com.sun.jna.Pointer. Then after call decrypt you extract string by Pointer.GetString and then call exported from go function for deallocating.

Answer (score 1):

Your `const char *` in `_GoString_` should use a `Pointer` instead, then use `Pointer.getString()` with the provided offset to obtain the actual string.

If Go itself is rejecting a `string` return value, you'll likely have to instead populate a buffer provided by the caller.